# How i can make injection with Kodein?

Tags: android, kotlin, kodein

I learn kodein lib for dependency injection just now. How i can take dependency value for variable?
My application class below, there i bind context with kodein:

```
class BaseApp : Application(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by Kodein.lazy {
        import(contextModule)
    }

    private val contextModule = Kodein.Module(CONTEXT_MODULE_TAG){
        bind<Context>(CONTEXT_TAG) with provider { this@BaseApp }
    }

    companion object{
        private const val CONTEXT_MODULE_TAG = "context_module"
        const val CONTEXT_TAG = "context_tag"
    }
}
```

In my repository class, i tried to take context, but not successfully.

```
class BatteryRepository : KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by kodein()
    private val context by instance<Context>(BaseApp.CONTEXT_TAG)
...
```

Where *kodein()* method call error:

> Expression 'kodein' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

How i can get context? Is it good idea to transfer context like that?

Comment: Is there a reason why your Repository class relies on the Android framework for retrieving data?

Comment: @ZUNJAE, yep, i use context for receiving some data.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Turns out that I was missing this dependency `import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein` (not sure why it was not automatically added by IDE)

Here is an example of `Kodein` + `AndroidX` libraries:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        ...
        android:name=".core.BaseApplication">
```

Application

```
open class BaseApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@BaseApplication))

        // import(otherCustomModule)
    }
}
```

Fragments

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import org.kodein.di.Kodein
import org.kodein.di.KodeinAware
import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein
import org.kodein.di.generic.kcontext

abstract class InjectionFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    final override val kodeinContext = kcontext<Fragment>(this)
    final override val kodein: Kodein by kodein()


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        kodeinTrigger?.trigger()
    }
}

// usage
class MyFragment() : InjectionFragment() {
    val someDependency: Type by instance()
}
```

Dependencies `app\build.gradle`

```
implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.3.2"
implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.3.2"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
```

**Extra**
It is also worth to override `kodeinTrigger` property (from `KodeinAware`). This way all the dependencies for `debug` builds will be resolved when Fragment is created, so app will fail instantly (as opposed to `release` builds where dependency is resolved only when it is used - some user paths may not crash the app)

```
abstract class InjectionFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    final override val kodeinContext = kcontext<Fragment>(this)
    final override val kodein: Kodein by kodein()
    final override val kodeinTrigger: KodeinTrigger? // See description in InjectionActivity
        get() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) KodeinTrigger() else super.kodeinTrigger

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        kodeinTrigger?.trigger()
    }
}
```

Edit:
Here is my project where everything is wired together https://github.com/igorwojda/Android-Showcase

Comment: I’d like to add that this import `import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein` is VERY important. For some reason it never auto imports and i’m on AS v3.5. Thanks for the great answer

Comment: thank you for this import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein. it was driving me crazy

Comment: This issue has been reported in Kotlin issue tracker
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33318 
Please vote

Comment: how to inject into a broadcast receiver ?